# aws elastic beanstalk war file deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, war

I am successfully rnning my spring RESTful service on local and have no errors in maven build. But when I setup tomcat environement with AWS and upload my war file in elastic beanstalk it shows its health degraded.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: A lot more info needed, but most likely you didn't set the entry point in AWS

Comment: u need to show what events are shown ! what are the errors happening

Comment: @Deepak WARN Environment health has transitioned from Severe to Degraded. Impaired services on all instances.
WARN Environment health has transitioned from Degraded to Severe. 100.0 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx. Impaired services on all instances.
2017-08-04 11:07:56 UTC+0500 WARN Environment health has transitioned from Severe to Degraded. Impaired services on all instances.

Comment: Here are some errors from error.log

Comment: 2017/08/04 07:09:24 [error] 29807#0: *3624 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 118.168.51.149, server: , request: "HEAD http://52.15.84.128:80/phpmyadmin2018/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/phpmyadmin2018/", host: "52.15.84.128"
2017/08/04 07:09:24 [error] 29807#0: *3626 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 118.168.51.149, server: , request: "HEAD http://52.15.84.128:80/phpmanager/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/phpmanager/", host: "52.15.84.128"

Comment: probably its an application issue as errors are 5xx

Comment: but application is running fine on localhost

Comment: Hi @TalhaZahid, did you fix the issue? i'm having the same issue.

Comment: I gave up with it and used EC2 :p

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. I found mistake in selecting environment.
Please check what environment you selected. For example if you have java jar file then it should be java , if you have java war file then you should opt GlassFish or tomcat.
Hope this is helpful for you